# Combinatorics problem; arranging marbles from bags.

Tags: combinatorics

I have 10 bags of marbles each of a different colour. For simplicity I will label the colours A,B,...,J. I need to know how many different ways I can make a 'super' bag of marbles which contains 176 marbles of any colour or more. Marbles of the same colour are indistinguishable and there is no limit to how many different colours the 'super' bag is made up of. I would also like to know how many arrangements there are in total. Combinatorics was never my forte. If the problem is too large, than pointers on how to approach the problem would also be appreciated.

Here is how many marbles each bag consists of:

Colour A: 123

Colour B: 90

Colour C: 69

Colour D: 40

Colour E: 9

Colour F: 8

Colour G: 6

Colour H: 2

Colour I: 2

Colour J: 1

Comment: What was your attempt ? If I were you, I would start with a smaller example.

Comment: Ok I have changed the problem, it is still big, but not as big. 

Now if I choose a colour then all of the marbles of that colour have to contribute to the 176. 

Possible combinations with 2 colours: (a,b), (a,c)
Possible combinations with 3 colours:(b,c,d),(a,b,c),(a,b,X),(a,c,X) where X={d,...,j} Thus there is 1 + 1 + 7 +7 = 16 different combinations of 3 colours to make up the 176 marbles.

Comment: I could keep going in this fashion but i'm getting the feeling it will be a bit of a nightmare to consider all the different duplicates when the number of different colours gets much higher. Do you see a more efficient way to do this?